# successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero

Tags: python, tensorflow

I started the tutorial about transfert learning with TF hub from tensorflow.org
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning_with_hub

and when I run it, I have this as result:

```
2020-02-10 10:49:00.817444: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-02-10 10:49:00.817538: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-02-10 10:49:00.817565: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:30] Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
Using TensorFlow backend.
2020-02-10 10:49:01.671573: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-02-10 10:49:01.686150: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-10 10:49:01.686802: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1070 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.7465GHz coreCount: 15 deviceMemorySize: 7.92GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 238.66GiB/s
2020-02-10 10:49:01.687014: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-02-10 10:49:01.688374: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-02-10 10:49:01.689491: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-02-10 10:49:01.689755: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-02-10 10:49:01.691268: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-02-10 10:49:01.692212: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-02-10 10:49:01.696243: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-02-10 10:49:01.696421: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-10 10:49:01.696934: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-10 10:49:01.697350: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-02-10 10:49:01.723450: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 3391195000 Hz
2020-02-10 10:49:01.724086: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x5cc4620 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-02-10 10:49:01.724110: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-02-10 10:49:01.801614: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-10 10:49:01.802276: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x5636b50 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-02-10 10:49:01.802298: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 1070, Compute Capability 6.1
2020-02-10 10:49:01.802464: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-10 10:49:01.802908: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1070 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.7465GHz coreCount: 15 deviceMemorySize: 7.92GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 238.66GiB/s
2020-02-10 10:49:01.802962: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-02-10 10:49:01.802983: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-02-10 10:49:01.802999: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-02-10 10:49:01.803022: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-02-10 10:49:01.803041: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-02-10 10:49:01.803057: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-02-10 10:49:01.803074: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-02-10 10:49:01.803126: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-10 10:49:01.803610: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-10 10:49:01.804030: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-02-10 10:49:01.804066: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-02-10 10:49:01.804854: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1096] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-02-10 10:49:01.804869: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102]      0 
2020-02-10 10:49:01.804878: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 0:   N 
2020-02-10 10:49:01.804969: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-10 10:49:01.805430: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-10 10:49:01.805876: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 7090 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
```

I think the problem comes from the gpu config but I don't know how to resolve it.
If anyone knows what to do ...